Masking Sensitive Data in Request Body
I'm working on implementing of lockback in a little spring project. When credentialDTO is passed in login end point, Spring generates a log line with apparent password.
2024-06-27 14:55:37,555 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.springframework.core.log.LogFormatUtils: Read "application/json;charset=UTF-8" to [CredentialDTO(username=user, password=12345)]

After mapping dto to real entity, the password is encoded and no problem the rest
I thought to avoid this behavior with a patternLayout and wrote a regex like "password\s*=\s*(.*?))]" just like in Baeuldung. But i wonder if there may be a better approach i don't know. Could we manipulate Spring logger directly to hide a field of a object during logging (maybe mark it with annotation) or maybe with an after process to mask the sensitive part? if this log was generated manually by us, i think we could have skipped or masked the marked field in log but in this case, i think there s no possible to do that. i don't have so much experience about logging with AOP but maybe it be the solution i m looking for. Could we use logging with AOP for this kind of purpose?
Could you give me an advice, an idea would be more efficient, if that is possible?

Why are you logging debug in the first place? My guess is  you are using lombok with generated dto's and a default toString. Write a dedicated toString for this object to exclude the password. Don't blow this up to a full blown AOP solution.

oh, is that all about its toString? :D you re definitely right about using lombok. i used @Data of lombok on DTOs. so its toSting. i spent a few hours for how to figure it out :D I really made it difficult. that s my bad. thank you so much.

but also i just wonder if this kind of approach is possible

Yes you could but it is like taking a canon and trying to kill a mosquito. It would be easier to create a logback filter / appender or the likes that obfuscates this (I do think spring already has one or something in place for this).

i got your point. i think rookies make it complicated than it is or want something to solve. :D keeping it simple is better. thank you again.

If you are using TLS throu https you are pretty safe since the http transport is secured.
If the client is compromised, you can not 99.999% solve this.
You could - however to solve the 0.0001% - create a salt on server-side, store it on server-side to the user's account, send the salt from the server to the browser, and use the salt to hash the password in the browser.
Then transport the hashed password+salt to the server only, on server-side you have to store the salt and the hash of the hashed passwort+salt only.
